# 2 dominios en route53 , 1 servidor EC2

Tags: aws, dns, ec2, amazon-web-services

tengo un dominio (Ej. www.miweb.cl ) en route53  que apunta a una instancia en EC2 de amazon 
- el problema es que no se como confiugurar un segundo dominio ( Ej www.mi-web.cl ) que quiero apuntarlo a la misma instancia de amazon

se que suena simple, pero no logro hacerlo

Comment: Puedes crear un record de tipo _cname_ cuyo nombre sea `www`, lo importante es como lo manejes en tu servidor en el archivo de configuración del proveedor http que estés utilizando

Comment: ya tengo www.miweb.cl como CNAME  a miweb.cl 
no puedo crear otro CNAME con www
`[name='www.miweb.cl.', type='CNAME'] but it already exists]`

Comment: Entonces la configuración la debes manejar en tu servidor dependiendo del sistema que utilices, ya sea `apache` o `nginx`